# Consistent implementation of PHP class constants (arrays not allowed)

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes

I'm currently writing a class:

```
final class MyTestClass {
  const URL = 'http://www.example.org';
  private static $MY_ARRAY = array('...');

  // since this is not allowed
  // const MY_ARRAY = array('...');
}
```

So my question is whether I should make *URL* a `private static` variable, too?
These values are constant and are only used in the class itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [PHP Constants Containing Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays) .  I think both are valid and also your current approach is fine. It's only important that you stick with one solution in your whole project.

Personally I think I would stay with your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that this question is on topic, however:

You have to understand what each variable definition is and what it means for the accesibility of that variable.

Say your class definition is as follows:

```
class MyTestClass {
  const URL = 'http://www.example.org';
  private static $MY_ARRAY = array('...');
}
```

And in the future you write another class that extends that class and it wants to update URL as below:

```
class SomeOtherClass extends MyTestClass {
  public __construct(){
    $this->URL = "http://www.someothersite.com";
  }
}
```

Now, if you never want URL to change, then that's fine. A better way to write `MyTestClass` however, would be:

```
class MyTestClass {
  private $URL = 'http://www.example.org';
  private $myArray = array();
}
```

Again however, if some class extends it, they won't be able to access the `$URL` var. Also, stay away from static.

Comment: This class will never be *extended* (now declared as `final` in the question). I just want to store a constant variable thus I took `const URL`, but PHP doesn't let me store arrays in there so my array variable will be declared as `private static`. Therefore I have to write both `MyTestClass::URL` and `self::$myArray` in the code. That's inconsitent in my opinion.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood, sorry.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for taking time to write the answer anyway ;)